# Kohana 3. Environment test page

Tags: php, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

I get environment test page going to any url.

I have this in bootstrap file

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

And i have this in my controller

```
public function action_index()
{
    $view = View::factory('test');
    $this->response->body($view);
}
```

So i have test.php file in my views directory. But anyways i get environment test page. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The controller action combination should be triggered when you go to your-uri/welcome/. Can you check the action is loaded with some debug info in it? Are there more routes defined? E.g. for the environment test page?

Comment: Did you remove the install.php?

Comment: Have you made sure your Welcome controller file is named correctly (Welcome.php) and defines the correct class (class Controller_Welcome) ?